# combine multiple data in ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax to run a MySQL query upon a user selecting a value from a dropdown box. I am wanting to pass the value from my first and second drop down box as a post onto the next page where the query can check to see if the value exists.

I am easily being able to pass the one value fine like so:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');

                $('#block').change(function() {
                    var sel_stud2 = $('#username_select').val();
//alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/block_user.php",
                        data: 'theOption2=' + sel_stud2,
                        success: function(whatigot) {
//alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            $('#LaDIV2').html(whatigot);
                            $('#theButton').click(function() {
                                alert('You clicked the button');
                            });
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax
                }); //END dropdown change event
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
```

However when I try to pass both my select drop down box values I get an index undefined error for both. here's what ive tried. please can someone show me where I am going wrong, thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');

                $('#block').change(function() {
                    var sel_stud2 = $('#username_select').val();
                    var sel_stud3 = $('#block').val();
//alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/block_user.php",
                        data: "{'theOption2=': + sel_stud2,'theOption3=': + sel_stud3}",  
                        success: function(whatigot) {
//alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            $('#LaDIV2').html(whatigot);
                            $('#theButton').click(function() {
                                alert('You clicked the button');
                            });
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax
                }); //END dropdown change event
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
```

Comment: try `{'theOption2': + sel_stud2,'theOption3': + sel_stud3}`

Comment: Why are you quoting your object??? `data: {theOption2:  sel_stud2, theOption3: sel_stud3},`

Comment: @bto.rdz I tried that and I tried it with the surrounding " " but it still gives an undefined error

Answer (score 0):

`@A. Wolff` is correct. You are quoting your object data (and your comment indicates you are still leaving the outer double-quotes):

Try this instead:

```
     data: {theOption2: sel_stud2,
            theOption3: sel_stud3},
```